# PHP header 404 not working with .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found')` is not working when I have this line in the .htaccess `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`?

How can I make it work so that I can keep `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]` - maybe there is a mistake in this line?

Also, even though I remove it, `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found')` is just showing `404.php` on the browrser, instead of pointing to 404.php and displaying the error message in that doc.

Below are my codes and files. They all are in the root dir for test.

index.php,

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
exit();
```

404.php,

```
echo "<h1>404 Not Found</h1>";
echo "The page that you have requested could not be found.";
```

.htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 404.php
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

For

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

I get this error,

> The requested URL /mywebsite/xxx/xxx/ was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

It is still not pointing to 404.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the `ErrorDocument` directive's [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument), it needs either absolute URL-path, so it starts with "/" or "http://" (or "https://"). Otherwise, it interprets the 2nd argument **as a message**.

It's the same scenario as:

```
ErrorDocument 404 Wildcard!
```

And if someone gets a 404 error, they'll see in their browser "Wildcard!".

You need to change it to a URL-path, like `/404.php`.

Comment: I tried that and I get this `The requested URL /mywebsite/xxx/xxx/ was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: @tealou you sure you have the right absolute path? The `/404.php` can't be relative to where the htaccess file is.

Comment: I now just have the problem with getting **the right absolute path**. any ideas? I just opened a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056404/how-can-i-capture-a-fully-qualified-local-url-path-with-mod-rewrite