# How can I capture a fully qualified local URL path with mod rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I capture a **fully qualified** local URL path with mod rewrite?

For instance, my project is located in `http://{localhost}/projects/mywebsite/index.php`

I tried with this `RewriteBase /projects/mywebsite/` but it does not work for `ErrorDocument`.

my .htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /projects/mywebsite/

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

I need to do `ErrorDocument 404  /projects/mywebsite/error.php` but it isn't dynamic. I have to change it in two places everytime for each project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ErrorDocument` doesn't accept any env variable unlike `mod_rewrite` rules. Here is what you can do:

1. Instead of `ErrorDocument` use `mod_rewrite` rules to handle 404 issues (see below)
2. Generate `RewriteBase` value dynamically using rules

You can use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically/dynamically
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

# use %{ENV:BASE} variable set above for routing file/dir not found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . %{ENV:BASE}error.php?e=404 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you very much! but why I get `'REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200' (length=3)` when I inspect `var_dump($_SERVER);` I thought it should be 404. Any ideas??

Comment: You will get 200 in `REDIRECT_STATUS`. That's why I passed `?e=404` in the query string so that you can use: `http_response_code($_GET['e']);` in your `error.php` code.

Comment: Were you able to use `http_response_code($_GET['e']);` in the code?

Comment: I am able to. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

The `ErrorDocument` is part of the apache core, it isn't affected by the Rewrite stuff which is a completely separate module.

If you need to output the contents of `error.php`, then output it from the php header() (based on your previous question) and don't rely on ErrorModule. Maybe something like:

```
header("HTTP/10 404 Not Found");
include("error.php");
```